# splitting a text file based on number of words in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I know to extract a subset of lines from a file I can do:

```
sed -n 2208202,2218201p file >>new
```

Is there a way in bash to extract a subset of a file (preserving the exact order) based on words? For example to extract the top 10k words of a file, or words from 10000 to 20000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this as the test file:

```
$ cat file
one two
three four five
six seven
eight nine
ten eleven twelve
thirteen
fourteen
```

Using GNU `awk` (`gawk`), let's select words 4 through 10:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '4<=NR && NR<=10{ printf "%s%s",$0,RT } END{print""}' file
four five
six seven
eight nine
ten
```

Note that this preserves the white space and line breaks of the the original file.

#### How it works

- `-v RS='[[:space:]]+'`

  This sets awk's record separator to any combination of white space.
- `4<=NR && NR<=10{ printf "%s%s",$0,RT }`

  For records 4 through 10, this prints the record with whatever whitespace followed it in the input file.  `RT` is not POSIX.
- `END{print""}`

  This prints a final newline which is needed if the final word was not the last on a line.

Comment: ++ for the record-terminator preservation; there's really no _specific_ `nawk` implementation; in practice, `nawk` is something like "any other `awk` than the original"; on Ubuntu, for instance, it is simply a _symlink_ to whatever `/usr/bin/awk` happens to be (which is `mawk` by default); `RT` is _GNU_ Awk-specific and is indeed not POSIX, but neither is a _multi-character_ `RS` value (POSIX only accepts a _literal, single-character_ value).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

- you define *word* as any run of non-whitespace characters
- you use *GNU* Awk or Mawk

try:

```
awk -v from=10000 -v to=20000 -v RS='[[:space:]]+' 'NR < from {next} NR > to {exit} 1' file
```

<sup>- Simply omit `-v from=...` to start with the *first* word.

- This solution *prints each word on its own line on output*; if, by contrast, you want to preserve the original whitespace between words, see [John1024's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37176308/45375).</sup>

- `RS='[[:space:]]+'` defines the input-record separator (`RS`) as any run of whitespace, which effectively makes each run of non-whitespace characters its own record.

  - It it is the use of a *multi-character* `RS` value that makes this solution non-POSIX-compliant; BSD `awk`, as also used on OS X, stays close to the POSIX spec. and therefore doesn't support such an `RS` value.
- `NR < from {next}` skips input records as long as their 1-based record index `NR` is below the start index of the range.
- `NR > to {exit}` *exits altogether once the record index exceeds the end index of the range.* This can be an important optimization with large input files.
- `1`, a common shorthand for `{ print }`, *prints each word on its own line*, because  `print` prints each input record followed by the value of `ORS`, the output-record separator, which defaults to `\n`.
- Caveat: A run of whitespace *preceding* the first word is reported as an *empty* word (record).

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

this should work with other awks too

```
$ awk -v n=15 'sum<n && p{print p} 
                         {p=$0; sum+=NF} 
                   sum>=n{exit} 
                      END{for(i=1;i<=n-sum+NF;i++) printf "%s ", $i; 
                          print ""}' file.txt
```

this is the first n words script. Range can be implemented similarly.

Comment: A valiant, but uneven attempt at a POSIX-compliant solution; the caveat is that what the `END` block outputs invariably _normalizes_ the line-internal whitespace (and (avoidably) adds a trailing space), unlike the rest of the script.